# Google Drive API Not Available

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

All of the sudden without any changes trying to save a file to Google Drive using

```
 Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(mGoogleApiClient)
                .createFile(mGoogleApiClient, changeSet, result.getDriveContents())
                .setResultCallback(fileCallback);
```

Shows a warning dialog that says "app requires one or more Google Play services that are not currently available..."

I didn't change any code so can anyone give me a clue as to what is wrong? Thank you

I also get the log

> Bad call: specified package com.google.android.gms under uid 10349 but it is really 10016

Also I am implementing this library

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:17.0.0"
```

Comment: You need google play  services in the emulator.

Comment: @Cucu I'm not using an emulator - it used to work on my phone which is weird

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Google Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/android) is deprecated. In order to use the Google Drive SDK you need to use drive REST APIs.

From the documentation:

> This API is deprecated. Clients must migrate to the [Drive REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/deprecation) or another suitable solution to avoid disruptions to your application.

Comment: Pretty much what I was really hoping wasn't the case, but thanks

Comment: Is there a nice library to use the Drive REST API  ?